# Changed the name of my Activity java file, how do I update xml reference?

Tags: java, android

So I decided to rename a few of my java classes with the refactor tool. It didn't however update the references in my XML files. I tried changing the reference manually by changing

from

```
    tools:context=".SomethingElse">
```

to

```
    tools:context=".CarbInput">
```

"CarbInput.java" is the new class name. And SomethingElse.java was the old class name.

This does not work. I can't find another reference to the java file inside the xml.

What am I missing?

Clarification : I am working in Android Studio

Comment: if your are on android studio , delete the line and write again, if that did not solve your problem clean your project , make and build it again

Comment: Is the package name in your manifest file ok?

Comment: @Christine I did spot an anomaly in the manifest! One of the files of which I had refactored the name had not been updated in the manifest.

Comment: Next time if you use refactor->rename it will also update the name in the AndroidManifest for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to spot the anomaly. It was in the AndroidManifest, the reference had not been updated.
It still looked like this.

```
    <activity android:name=".SomethingElse" />
```

So I manually changed it to

```
    <activity android:name=".CarbInput" />
```

Comment: Although, the issue is resolved. I'd suggest if you want to rename a file/class/var, do so by right-clicking the item and selecting refactor/rename. This will take care of whatever is required for renaming (e.g. updating AndroidManifest for any Activity/Service class renaming).